# Ruby on Rails Scaffolding : Two foreign keys for the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scaffolding

I'm a beginner to ruby on rails that's migrating an access database to RoR.

In the database there is a table named `tasks` and a table named `users`.

The table `tasks` has two foreign keys to the table `users`: `task_created_by` and `task_finished_by`.

I wanted to create everything using the scaffold tool. Is it possible?

Also, which name should I give to the two foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found here [Rails: Scaffold to automatically do one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502119/rails-scaffold-to-automatically-do-one-to-many-relationship) that it isn't possible to scaffold relationships with the scaffold tool itself but there's a plugin called [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/), [Streamlined](http://www.streamlinedframework.org/), [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/) and [AutoAdmin](http://code.trebex.net/auto-admin) that allows us to scaffold with associations.