# Foreign Key Dropdown in Scaffold Rails 3 Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I created 2 models using scaffolding with Rails 3. The models are Locations and Jobs and each job has a location.

I created the required reference calls in the scaffold generation code but when I look at the view to create a new job, all I see is a textbox where I should add the location_id.

How can I get that to be a dropdown instead for a better user experience?

Comment: A duplicate of [Rails: Scaffold to automatically do one-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502119/rails-scaffold-to-automatically-do-one-to-many-relationship) The behavior that you want will come from a third party.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imagine, that you have got `title` for each location

```
<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :title %>
```

API: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: I think this should be `:location_id` otherwise you get an `undefined local variable or method` error.